# Multiple Where & Or MS Access Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a list box and a search button in my MS Access form. The user selects the customer they would like to search stock for. Then a keyword from a textfield to search multiple fields.

This is what I have so far but clearly something is just slightly off and getting a syntax error.

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT tblPartsAndConsumables.[DESCRIPTION], tblPartsAndConsumables.[P/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.[S/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.[B/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.QTY, tblPartsAndConsumables.[EXPIRY DATE], tblPartsAndConsumables.LOCATION, tblPartsAndConsumables.Attachments " _
    & " FROM tblPartsAndConsumables " _
    & "WHERE [Customer Name] LIKE  '*" & Me.CustomerListbox.Value & "*' " _
    & "WHERE [DESCRIPTION] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [P/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [S/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [B/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*'" _
    & " ORDER BY tblPartsAndConsumables.[DESCRIPTION], tblPartsAndConsumables.[P/N]; "

    Me.SubFormSearch.Form.RecordSource = SQL
    Me.SubFormSearch.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Two `WHERE` clauses would be a problem.  Probably use an `AND` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two where  ...but you should use only one  use  OR

```
    SQL = "SELECT tblPartsAndConsumables.[DESCRIPTION], tblPartsAndConsumables.[P/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.[S/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.[B/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.QTY, tblPartsAndConsumables.[EXPIRY DATE], tblPartsAndConsumables.LOCATION, tblPartsAndConsumables.Attachments " _
    & " FROM tblPartsAndConsumables " _
    & "WHERE [Customer Name] LIKE  '*" & Me.CustomerListbox.Value & "*' " _
    & " OR  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [P/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [S/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [B/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*'" _
    & " ORDER BY tblPartsAndConsumables.[DESCRIPTION], tblPartsAndConsumables.[P/N]; "
```

If the "here clause must work togheter then you need  AND  eg: "

```
    SQL = "SELECT tblPartsAndConsumables.[DESCRIPTION], tblPartsAndConsumables.[P/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.[S/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.[B/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.QTY, tblPartsAndConsumables.[EXPIRY DATE], tblPartsAndConsumables.LOCATION, tblPartsAndConsumables.Attachments " _
    & " FROM tblPartsAndConsumables " _
    & "WHERE [Customer Name] LIKE  '*" & Me.CustomerListbox.Value & "*' " _
    & " AND   [DESCRIPTION] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & " ADN ( [P/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [S/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [B/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox  & "*' )" _
    & " ORDER BY tblPartsAndConsumables.[DESCRIPTION], tblPartsAndConsumables.[P/N]; "
```

OR

```
    SQL = "SELECT tblPartsAndConsumables.[DESCRIPTION], tblPartsAndConsumables.[P/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.[S/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.[B/N], tblPartsAndConsumables.QTY, tblPartsAndConsumables.[EXPIRY DATE], tblPartsAndConsumables.LOCATION, tblPartsAndConsumables.Attachments " _
    & " FROM tblPartsAndConsumables " _
    & "WHERE [Customer Name] LIKE  '*" & Me.CustomerListbox.Value & "*' " _
    & " AND (  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & " OR   [P/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [S/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox & "*' " _
    & "OR [B/N] LIKE  '*" & Me.Searchbox  & "*' )" _
    & " ORDER BY tblPartsAndConsumables.[DESCRIPTION], tblPartsAndConsumables.[P/N]; "
```

Comment: both Where clauses need to be met though

Comment: The important thing is that now it works .. check if there are other problems ..

Comment: correct, the (customer Name) AND.. (description or p/n or s/n or b/n)

Comment: answer  updated  with a  two sample with AND  ..  hope one of this i what you are looking for